# Python Solution vs C++ Solution of leetcode 1039

Tags: python, c++, dynamic-programming

[Leetcode 1039](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-score-triangulation-of-polygon/)

I have written a code in python.

```
class Solution(object):
    def minScoreTriangulation(self, A):
        self.dp = [[-1]*len(A)]*len(A)
        ret = self.calc(A, 0, len(A)-1)
        return ret

    def calc(self, A, x, y):
        if math.ceil(y-x) < 2:
            return 0

        if self.dp[x][y] != -1:
            return self.dp[x][y]

        mn = sys.maxint
        for i in range(x+1, y):
            mn = min(mn, (self.calc(A, x, i) + self.calc(A, i, y) + A[x]*A[y]*A[i]))

        self.dp[x][y] = mn
        return mn
```

I have also written a C++ Solution with the same logic.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int minScoreTriangulation(vector<int>& A) {
        vector<int> row(A.size(), -1);
        vector<vector<int>> dp(A.size(), row);

        int ret =calc(dp, A, 0, A.size()-1);

        return ret;
    }

    int calc(vector<vector<int>>& dp, vector<int>& A, int x, int y)
    {
        if ((y-x) < 2)
            return 0;

        if(dp[x][y] != -1) return dp[x][y];

        int mn = INT_MAX;

        for( int i=x+1; i<y ; i++)
        {
            mn = min(mn, calc(dp, A, x, i)+calc(dp, A, i, y)+A[x]*A[y]*A[i]);
        }
        dp[x][y] =mn;
        return mn;
    }
};
```

The python solution giving me Wrong Answer.
Can some please explain what is the problem with my python solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You might be on the wrong stack exchange, you should go there https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BlueSheepToken This is definitely not on-topic on Code Review.

Comment: @Peilonrayz My bad, I thought so. Why shouldnt it be? On which stackexchange should it be? (Definitely not on SO either)

Comment: @BlueSheepToken "[Code Review is for open-ended questions about code that already works correctly (to the best of your knowledge). Questions seeking help about debugging or understanding code are off-topic for Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)". I only know the rules for Code Review, and so can't comment on other sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
self.dp = [[-1]*len(A)]*len(A)
```

In python, you can not use this way to initialize a 2d array, because it will reference to the same `[-1]*len(A)`, change to:

```
self.dp = [[-1]*len(A) for i in range(len(A))]
```

It will work fine.